# How do I log to an Activity (via Javascript) from inside a WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, logging, webview

I need to perform some logging within my embedded WebView javascript, and ideally I could call Log.d in the encasing Activity.  If that's not possible, what's the next/best alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WebView can intercept a prompt js message threw by your javascript.
You just had to create a message like "LOG.Your log message" and when your application receive it, parse this message to understant that your javascript want to Log something and that the Log value is "Your log message".
This is how PhoneGap works.

In your javascript:
 `prompt('LOG.Your log message');`
In your java code: set a new `WebChromeClient` to your `WebView` where your override the `onJsPrompt` method
method description here: [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onJsPrompt%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.JsPromptResult%29)

Comment: great. so... what mechanism do I use for this? both in javascript and in the Activity.... what method does the javascript call to send messages and what listener do I use to receive them?